# HERE MAPS: Autosuggest Places for Angular

Tags: typescript, here-api

I'm trying to implement Autosuggest Places from HERE Maps to the Angular project, but it seems like there is no option to use /autosuggest endpoint?

Is there any workaround to get autosuggested values with full location response?
If I use "Suggest", then the response is just address name.

I've set up the project as described by Nic Raboy on https://developer.here.com/blog/display-here-maps-angular-web-application

For getting autosuggested values, I would love to use something like this ( that should make sense based on the documentation ):

```
declare let H;
...
private platform: any;

...

this.platform = new H.service.Platform({
      app_id: <app_id>,
      app_code: <app_code>
    });
...

const place = this.f.address.value;
const parameters = {
   at: '52.5113,13.3791',
   q: place
};

const places = this.platform.getPlacesService();
places.autosuggest(parameters, 
    result => {
      console.log(result);
    }, error => {
      reject(error);
    });
```

places.autosuggest does not exists, and based on the v3_3.0.mapsjs-service.js, places only support: "Suggest", "Explore", "Around", "Here", "Caetgories".

Comment: I am getting blank map with here logo in bottom. Can you please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods *suggest*, *explore*, and others from the Maps JavaScript API, are convenient wrappers around Places API REST endpoints.

You can get results from Places Autosuggest, by using the Angular HttpClient class and calling the **[Autosuggest API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics_api/resource-autosuggest.html)** *directly*.

This will be something along the lines of:

```
this.http.get<AutosuggestResult>(
   'https://places.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest',
  { params }
)
```

Comment: I was sure I've tried this already, and had an issue with OPTIONS request.
Tried it now again, and it's working perfectly. To bad there is no wrapper for this as well, but this will suffice. Thank you! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Indeed, there could have been a method for that one too. On the other hand, you get more flexibility by skipping one abstraction level on top of the rest api.